# Folium: export coordinates from markers

Tags: python, markers, folium

I'm looking for a way to export the coordinates from markers on the map in folium. I know that one can get the coordinates over the current mouse position, but I would like to use this information for another problem.

Ideally I would like to be able to move a marker and get the new coordinates of this marker.
At the moment my markers are defined as follows:

```
def add_markers(coordinates, building):
  marker = folium.Marker(
    location=coordinates,
    popup=(f"<stong>{building}</stong>"),
    draggable=True)
  marker.add_to(map_with_markers)
```

When I move the marker on the map this is not saved anywhere and also the coordinates of the marker stay the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least at Folium v0.13 that's not seem to be possible. Check [issue #1578](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1578)  in folium's github repository.

If you are using Jupyter to render your maps, I suggest you to try a different library like [ipyleaflet](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It has a great interactive features. Check [this blog post](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-mouse-events-on-ipyleaflet-4d002097efc0) for an example of what you ask for. I paste here a resume:

```py
# Define a callback function for an event on a marker
def handle_observe(event):
    print(event)

# Call the callback function whenever the location of the marker changes
marker.observe(handle_observe, 'location')
```